# subquery the same table in select statement

Tags: sql

I have a resturant db and I need to total up the total value of all the items sold individually. So if I sold a hamburger that has a base price of $10.00 with bacon which costs $1.00 and a hambuger(again $10.00) with avacado that costs $0.50 I need to get $21.50 returned. My invoice table looks like this:

```
invoice_num item_num  price   item_id   parent_item_id
111         hmbg      10.00   guid_1    ''
111         bacn      1.00    guid_2    guid_2
112         hmbg      10.00   guid_3    ''
112         avcd      0.50    guid_4    guid_3
```

I can get the sum of all the parent items like this:

```
SELECT item_num, SUM(price) FROM invoices WHERE parent_item_id = ''
```

it is the adding of the toppings that is confusing me. I feel like I need to add a subquery in the SUM but I'm not sure how to go about doing it and referencing the original query to use the item_id.

Comment: SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: This does not make sense to me -- 2 problems.  1) You have two invoice numbers, what about these rows shows they need to be totaled to 21.50?  2) Should the 2nd row have a parent_item_id of guid_1?

Comment: @Hogan, combo-breaker!

Comment: @aleksey.berezan - Access was mentioned in the 2nd comment.  You broke the trend so then I went with new content. :D

Comment: @Hogan, oh, I should have written firebird :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT item_num, sum(i.price) + sum(nvl(x.ingred_price,0))
  FROM invoices i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT parent_item_id
             , sum(price) ingred_price
          FROM invoices
         WHERE parent_item_id IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY parent_item_id) x
ON x.parent_item_id = i.item_id
WHERE i.parent_item_id IS NULL      
GROUP BY item_num
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb532/1) that proves the above code works. I used Oracle, but you should be able to adapt it to whatever DB you are using.

Assumption: You don't have more than one level in a parent child relationship. E.g. A can have a child B, but B won't have any other children.

Comment: Won't the sub-query give values across invoices (eg we both get bacon(!)) both our burgers will get counted in the sub-query)

Comment: @dcp it works for two levels, for more general query see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not clear based on your question (see my comment) but as I understand it a simple group by will give you what you want.  If not please explain (in the original question) why does this query does  not work --- what is it missing from your requirements?

```
SELECT item_num, SUM(price) 
FROM invoices
GROUP BY item_num
```

Comment: how this one could return 21.5 in any row?

Comment: I need the totals for all the hamburgers sold including their toppings(so I don't want an entry for bacon or avocado) for all invoices not just on one.  I apologize if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but looks like you need [recursive cte](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT).
Here's example for PostgreSQL:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select
        t.invoice_num, t.price, t.item_id, t.item_num
    from Table1 as t
    where t.parent_item_id is null
    union all
    select
        t.invoice_num, t.price, t.item_id, c.item_num
    from Table1 as t
        inner join cte as c on c.item_id = t.parent_item_id
)
select invoice_num, item_num, sum(price)
from cte
group by invoice_num, item_num
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/37a6e/4)</kbd>**

I've used `null` for empty `parent_item_id` (it's better solution than using empty strings), but you can change this to `''`.